# Webview and navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I have a webview in my swift app with a bunch of links on the website it is connected to. When a link is pressed, how do I make it so instead of opening the link in the same view, make it open in a new view with a back button (navigation controller). My viewcontroller.swift code is below. Any help?

```
     import UIKit
        import Parse
        import PKHUD

        class Home: UIViewController {

            @IBOutlet var homeweb: UIWebView!
            @IBOutlet var HomeActivity: UIActivityIndicatorView!

            var request: NSURLRequest? = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://google.com")!)
            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
if navigationController?.viewControllers.count > 1 { navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil }
                PKHUD.sharedHUD.contentView = PKHUDSuccessView()
                PKHUD.sharedHUD.show()
                PKHUD.sharedHUD.dimsBackground.boolValue
                PKHUD.sharedHUD.userInteractionOnUnderlyingViewsEnabled.boolValue
                PKHUD.sharedHUD.hide(afterDelay: 3.0);
                if let request = request {
                    homeweb.loadRequest(request)
                }
            }
        }

        extension Home: UIWebViewDelegate {
            func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
                if request != self.request && navigationType != .Other {
                    if let Home = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("homeview") as? Home {
                        Home.request = request
                        navigationController?.pushViewController(Home, animated: true)
                        return false
                    }
                }

                return true
            }

            override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
                super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
                // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
            }

            func webViewDidStartLoad(homeweb: UIWebView)
            {
                HomeActivity.startAnimating()
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
            }
            func webViewDidFinishLoad(homeweb: UIWebView)
            {
                HomeActivity.stopAnimating()
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                title = homeweb.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.title")
            }

            @IBAction func about(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "About Ball00n", message: "Copyright ©2014-2015                 GreenBalloon, LLC                         James Cozzi (jc0z)                  jamescozzi00@gmail.com                    balloonhack.webs.com", preferredStyle: .Alert)

                let Action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)

                alertController.addAction(Action1)

                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the viewcontroller to be the webview's delegate and implement the following method:

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
  // check for your specific condition
  if request.URL?.absoluteString == "some link" {
    // push viewcontroller here or perform a segue
    return false // to not follow the link in the webview
  }

  return true
}
```

now - after understanding what you really try to achieve :) - i did the following:

setup a viewcontroller in storyboard with just a webview all over the screen. ctrl drag from the webview to the webviewcontroller and set it to be its delegate. set the viewcontroller to a custom class "WebViewController". also set the storyboard ID to "WebViewController". drag from the webview to the WebViewController class and connect an IBOutlet called "webView". finally your WebViewController class should look like this:

```
import UIKit

class WebViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

  var request: NSURLRequest? = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://YOUR_INITIAL_WEBSITE")!)

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if navigationController?.viewControllers.count > 1 {
      navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
    }

    if let request = request {
      webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
  }
}

extension WebViewController: UIWebViewDelegate {
  func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if request != self.request && navigationType != .Other {
      if let webViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WebViewController") as? WebViewController {
        webViewController.request = request
        navigationController?.pushViewController(webViewController, animated: true)
        return false
      }
    }

    return true
  }

  func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    title = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.title")
  }
}
```

at least this is a start :)

Comment: What if it's not a specific link? What if it's any link? @Andre Slotta

Comment: So you want to open a new view if ANY link is clicked? Then you simply push the new viewcontroller and return false.

Comment: Where you say "push controller here", what do I put? When I put your code into my ViewController.swift, the links still open in the same webview. @Andre Slotta

Comment: can you show me your viewcontroller's code somehow?

Comment: Okay and is there something I need to add to the storyboard too? I have a tab bar controller connected to a navigation controller, which is connected to a view controller. @AndreSlotta

Comment: you have to ctrl drag from the webview to its viewcontroller and set the delegate - you can also do that in code: `webView.delegate = self` where self points to the viewcontroller. and you have to make your viewcontroller conform to the protocol accordingly: `class YourViewControllerClass: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {`

Comment: ok. right now your webview should not show any webpage even though you load a request. am i right?

Comment: No. When the app is opened, the webpage loads up. What I want is that when a link is selected on that webpage, a new view is loaded with a back button to go back to the previous webpage. Basically, for every page on the website, I want a new view with the navigation controller. @Andre Slotta

Comment: 1. the webpage should not load because you `return false` in that `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method. so something seems to be wrong. 2. why do you want to create a new view for every website?

Comment: Here's a video of what I want. http://youtube.com/watch?v=vYFjnpwiyZM @Andre Slotta

Comment: So do you have anything?

Comment: I get an error for the extension string: Declaration is only valid at file scope

Comment: where exactly? are you sure that you put the extension stuff OUTSIDE the webviewcontroller class?

Comment: extension WebViewController: UIWebViewDelegate { this string

Comment: again: are you sure that you did not put the extension INSIDE the class but OUTSIDE of it?

Comment: 1. you have to add one more **}** after `homeweb.loadRequest(request)` so that there are three closing brackets. 2. the delegate method in the extension has to be called `func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool` and not `func homeweb(homeweb: UIWebView, shouldStartWithLoadRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType:UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool`...

Comment: I named my IBOutlet Home. Also, when I insert a third closing curly brace, I get a bunch of errors.

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything works except for one thing. When I select a link and it goes to another view, I do not get a back button.

Comment: I have a bar button where the back button should be. I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: i think it replaces the back button. what barbuttonitem do you have there? can you place it somewhere else?

Comment: It's a button that displays an alert view. I don't know if I can place anywhere else.

Comment: Is there a way to replace the button and then make it reappear when the home page is present?

Comment: try and update your `viewDidLoad` like i did in my post!

Comment: Can I just paste my entire viewcontroller.swift?

Comment: you did not update your `viewDidLoad` as i told you. you have to add the following: `if navigationController?.viewControllers.count > 1 {
      navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
    }`

Comment: Yes it works! How do I color the back button? All my buttons are a shade of green, but the default is blue.

Comment: go to your storyboard and change the **global tint** in the file inspector.

Comment: You have been a huge help. Thank you so much. A couple things, I have a refresh button above the web view, how do I make it so when it's clicked it calls the original webpage (with no back button) and reloads it?

Comment: you're welcome. but i can't answer all your questions in a comment conversation... pay me and i do it all for you. ;)

Comment: we should not discuss that in the comments... :)